# React Native AWS image upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, react-native

I am making an app in React native and will be using Amazon Web Services for image upload, I was wondering if the AWS node SDK can be used in my React Native app because I have read multiple outdated blogposts that said they were having issues, any one tried it out? (Node version: 4)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS Node SDK relies on several Node libraries like `http` that don't exist in React Native and are likely hard to reimplement faithfully. What I'd do is either use the native AWS SDKs and bridge them to JS, or write a small JS client just for S3 and look at the AWS Node SDK to see how they do authentication.

Answer (score 0):

there is existing node packages like `react-native-aws-signature` that can help you do the authentication for AWS request for React-Native.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a new library that has just been released to the official AWS repository which has full React Native support including a Storage module for interacting with S3 using signed requests: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify